# PostgreSQL: group with most common items: handling overlapping items

Tags: sql, postgresql

Postgresql: 9.3
I have a long log of "shopping cart ids" and the "product ids" each shopping cart contains.
I'm looking for a way to create groups that have the most "product ids" in common. The "product ids" can be in multiple groups at the same time.

As a result I need the "shopping cart ids","product ids" and the name of the groups (group 1, group 2, ...).

If anyone have a hint on how to do it. I know a SQL query is not ideal for it but it's all I have at the moment.

EDIT: With the below query I know groups of xx Shopping Carts have xx Products in common.

```html
WITH a AS (
SELECT Shopping_Cart.Product_Id AS Product_Id, count(Shopping_Cart.Product_Id) AS "count" FROM Shopping_Cart 
GROUP BY Shopping_Cart.Product_Id
ORDER BY "count"
) 

SELECT a."count" AS "Product in Common", count(DISTINCT Shopping_Cart.id) AS "Shopping Cart Count" FROM a
RIGHT JOIN Shopping_Cart ON Shopping_Cart.Product_Id = a.Product_Id
GROUP BY  a."count"
```

It's better than nothing but if I have 7 shoppers with items 1,2,3 and 7 shoppers with items 4,5,6 they fall into the same group of shoppers with 3 items in common. I need to separate them.

Comment: what's the size of the groups? 2 products?, n products?

Comment: Please edit your question is sample data and desired results.  It seems poorly described.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you might want to loop through your Product table joining back on your Shopping table by CartId.  maybe something like

DECLARE
    ProdId Product%rowtype;

BEGIN
    FOR ProdId IN SELECT "Product Id" from ProductTable

```
LOOP
    SELECT ProdId,ProductId,count(CartId) 
    From ShoppingTable where CartId in 
    (Select Distinct CartId from Shopping where ProductId = ProdId) 
    GROUP BY ProdId,ProductId
    ORDER by count(CartId) Desc

RETURN NEXt ProdId;

END LOOP;

RETURN;
```

END

LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' ;